# fabricjs , After rotating object is it possible to get left,top and right position of viritual rectagle

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

[image: preview]

After rotating object is it possible to get left,top and right position of virtual rectangle?

Comment: Btw, how about plain old `Math.sin`/`Math.cos` and Pythagorean theorem? Rotating an object doesn't change it's size.

Answer (score 7):

What you are looking for is the *bounding rect* of your object:

> **getBoundingRect**(*ignoreVpt*) → {Object} Returns coordinates of object's
>   bounding rectangle (left, top, width, height) the box is intented as
>   aligned to axis of canvas.
>
> Returns: Object with left, top, width, height properties Type Object
>
> reference: [fabricjs sourcecode](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.js.html#line13672)

```js
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
fabric.Object.prototype.transparentCorners = false;
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 120,
  top: 30,
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  fill: 'green',
  angle: 20
});

canvas.on('after:render', function() {
  canvas.contextContainer.strokeStyle = '#555';
  canvas.forEachObject(function(obj) {
    var bound = obj.getBoundingRect(); // <== this is the magic
    console.log(bound);
    canvas.contextContainer.strokeRect(
      bound.left,
      bound.top,
      bound.width,
      bound.height
    );

  });

});
canvas.add(rect);
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas height=200 width=300 id="c" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>
```

Since the `after:render` event is fired continuously after each frame is rendered you can see the updated bounding box of your object for every update, in position, rotation and dimensions.

```js
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
fabric.Object.prototype.transparentCorners = false;
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 120,
  top: 30,
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  fill: 'green',
  angle: 20
});
canvas.add(rect);
canvas.on('after:render', function() {
  canvas.contextContainer.strokeStyle = '#555';
  var ao = canvas.getActiveObject();
  if (ao) {
    var bound = ao.getBoundingRect();

    canvas.contextContainer.strokeRect(
      bound.left,
      bound.top,
      bound.width,
      bound.height
    );
    console.log(bound);

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas height=200 width=300 id="c" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>
```

For reference [Working with events](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/wiki/Working-with-events)

Comment: Hey! Thanks Inferon. This is exactly what I was looking for. I'll integrate this today.

Comment: Hi Inferon. I tried the solution. The only problem i am facing that 'ob' does not reflacts on dragging object. The coords return only when i leave mouse button and start dragging again. I want realtime coords while dragging. Here is my code.
 
CANVAS.on('object:render',function(){
  
            ob=Math.round(Math.floor(activeObject.getBoundingRect().left));
                console.log("LEFT COORDS "+ob);
})

Comment: Hi Inferon, This is exactly I was doing but problem was fabric.js library. When I used your source file (rawgit.com) , this works fine now (May be the version issue). Thanks a lot for saving my hours.

Comment: @kabrice could you elaborate? I don't understand your issue sorry